How to Apply LabelEncoder to a Polars DataFrame Column?
I'm trying to use scikit-learn's LabelEncoder with a Polars DataFrame to encode a categorical column. I am using the following code.
import polars as pl

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Color" : ["red","white","blue"]
})

enc = LabelEncoder()

However, an error is raised.

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead.

Next, I tried converting the column to a NumPy.
df.with_columns(
    enc.fit_transform(pl.col("Color").to_numpy()) 
)

Now, a different error is raised.

AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Note. I found that .cast(pl.Categorical).to_physical() could be used to obtain the desired result. Still, I'd prefer using something like transform() on my test dataset.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Color").cast(pl.Categorical).to_physical().alias("Color_encoded")
)


For such a call to an external API taking an entire sequence of values, such as enc.fit_transform, pl.Expr.map_batches could be used.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Color").map_batches(enc.fit_transform)
)

shape: (3, 1)
┌───────┐
│ Color │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1     │
│ 2     │
│ 0     │
└───────┘

Note. It would be nice if enc.set_output("polars") (as outlined in this answer) was available for the LabelEncoder. However, this is not implemented.

You already shared an approach to label encoding a column using polars' native expression API. A cleaner way could rely on dense ranking as follows.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Color").rank("dense") - 1
)

Subtraction is used only to obtain an output with lowest label being 0.

Hi @Hericks! i've found the .rank too, but im not sure how to apply it with the same labels on my test dataset

@Simon In that case, a stateful approach using a LabelEncoder seems appropriate.

Enum type might do what you're looking for wrt statefulness. Depends on your overall process and willingness to refactor.

As a follow up to my comment in the other answer, there are Enum types with which you could do
Colors=pl.Enum(SO['Color'].unique().sort())

SO=SO.with_columns(pl.col("Color").cast(Colors)).with_columns(i=pl.col("Color").to_physical())

If you know the colors in advance then you could do
Colors = pl.Enum(sorted(["red","white","blue"]))
SO = pl.DataFrame(
    {"Color" : ["red","white","blue"]}, schema={'Color': Colors}
)
SO.with_columns(i=pl.col("Color").to_physical())

Adding a color isn't as simple as with a stateful class, you'd have to make a new Enum and cast the existing columns to that new one. For example
Colors=pl.Enum(Colors.categories.append(pl.Series(['orange'])))
SO=SO.with_columns(pl.col("Color").cast(Colors))

